# Restart USB plugged device without restarting a computer

Tags: windows-xp, restart, gsm

I am dealing with an issue that USB GSM modem throws an exception and is in the failed state until you SHUT DOWN and turn on the PC again.

The "restart" does not help, because it only flushes the memory (running on Windows XP, SP3 Pro.)

As I suspect, the problem might be solved when the USB's power goes off and on again.

But is there a way how to do it without shuting the whole PC down (Like remove and add the device in device manager)?

Also do you know how can I simulate this state? It happends randomely and I am unable to do it at my will.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You say it is a USB device (i.e. not integrated).   The only reliable way to re-power the device, apart from re-booting the PC, is to unplug and re-plug the device (which is quicker anyway).

There's a discussion here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/326d26e7-baa9-45b4-8234-321c9e5f8ffa/

The exception is happening in the device, and without knowing what causes it, you can't reliably reproduce it.  Maybe the device vendor has some software that would help you collect its logs.